# Single word for honesty about limitations/weaknesses?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there a single word for honesty about limitations/weaknesses?

E.g., accountability?  humility?

I am updating based on the comments.  My main interest is to say: we have some idea.  We want to improve the reach of the idea. However, the idea has limitations.  We also want to be forthright about the limitations--it's a major goal. Our objective therefore is to

Increase the reach, but also the * of the idea.

Where * = honesty about limitations

Comment: What's wrong with "humility" and why doesn't it fit?

Comment: Insight? .......

Comment: Straightforwardness?

Comment: I like candour.

Comment: So ... you want to "increase reach" and "increase honesty (about limitations)"?

Comment: It is possible to evangelize an idea but also be *upfront* about its failings.

Comment: As you ask it, there is no single word for honesty about limitations/weaknesses, nor is there an equivalent phrase.
“Honesty” would have been a fine solution but you rejected that. “Openness” still seems to a fine solution.
Could you please explain why “honesty” isn’t sufficient, and yours has to refer specifically to “limitations/weaknesses”?
Did you notice, neither “honesty” nor anything like it could match your *?
Did you notice also, “but” is a lot less likely to fit your concept than “and” would?
Why not just stick with “Increase the reach of the idea” and live the ret alone?

Answer (score 0):

Humility is an okay choice, but it doesn't really convey willingness to admit personal flaws.

**Forthcoming** seems closer to what you want.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forthcoming):

> 2 b : characterized by openness, candidness, and forthrightness

Comment: Forthcoming is an adjective; I think the OP is asking for a noun. I would pick candour.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The *speaker* might be candid, but I'd not sure that works with the *idea*. OP's template: "* of the idea".